# Calling scala code in pyspark for XSLT transformations

Tags: scala, apache-spark, xslt, pyspark

This might be a long shot, but figured it couldn't hurt to ask.  I'm attempting to use [Elsevier's open-sourced `spark-xml-utils` package](https://github.com/elsevierlabs-os/spark-xml-utils) in pyspark to transform some XML records with XSLT.

I've had a bit of success with some exploratory code getting a transformation to work:

```
# open XSLT processor from spark's jvm context
with open('/tmp/foo.xsl', 'r') as f:
    proc = sc._jvm.com.elsevier.spark_xml_utils.xslt.XSLTProcessor.getInstance(f.read())


# transform XML record with 'proc' 
with open('/tmp/bar.xml','r') as f:
    transformed = proc.transform(f.read())
```

However, in a more realistic situation, I was unable to drop the `proc.transform` into a `lambda` map function, getting errors similar to:

> "An error occurred while calling o55.**getstate**. Trace:
>   py4j.Py4JException: Method **getstate**([]) does not exist at
>   py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:318)
>   at
>   py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:326)
>   at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:272) at
>   py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
>   at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79) at
>   py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214) at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)"

When I got the small example to work on a single record, that was operating in a pyspark shell, which I'm assuming was using the spark driver.  But in the map function mentioned above, this was in Spark, via Livy and YARN, which introduces workers.  This [SO question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40853797/1196358) suggests that perhaps I cannot use the function from the jvm in that context.

Now, the `spark-xml-utils` library provides some examples in scala, doing precisely what I'd like to do:

```
import com.elsevier.spark_xml_utils.xslt.XSLTProcessor

val xmlKeyPair = sc.sequenceFile[String, String]("s3n://spark-xml-utils/xml/part*")

val stylesheet = sc.textFile("s3n://spark-xml-utils/stylesheets/srctitle.xsl").collect.head

val srctitles = xmlKeyPair.mapPartitions(recsIter => { 
    val proc = XSLTProcessor.getInstance(stylesheet)
    recsIter.map(rec => proc.transform(rec._2))
})
```

I'm wondering, how can I translate this to pyspark code, such that I could run it over an RDD?  Ideally, on an RDD with the following input and output format:

```
id | document | other | columns
-----------------------------------------------------
sprog | <xml here...> | more | data
baz   | <xml here...> | more | data
```

that could become

```
id | document | other | columns
-----------------------------------------------------
sprog | <*transformed* xml here...> | more | data
baz   | <*transformed* xml here...> | more | data
```

Any help or suggestions would be most appreciated.

**Update 8/28/2018:** Also tried running through `mapPartitions`, no dice.  Same error of `__getstate__()`

Comment: No, it's not possible to do this directly from pyspark since you need to call `spark-xml-utils` classes from _executors_, i.e. transformation functions. Here's a good explanation why: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34412182/2271325

Comment: A possible workaround is to implement a Scala UDF that would simply call `spark-xml-utils` classes. In this case, you'll have to use DataFrame API instead of RDD.

Comment: Thanks @SergeyKhudyakov for the thoughts.  In the interim since posting, started to grok the idea that executors could not call `spark-xml-utils` classes.  But, more, appreciate the proposed workaround of scala UDFs; have not used those before and didn't realize they could be called from pyspark context.  Looking into that now.

Comment: If you already use Python why not use relevant Python tools? `lxml` supports XSLT transforms for example.

Comment: @user6910411, I should have clarified in my post.  I need it to support XSLT 2.0, which lxml currently does not I believe.  That was my original approach until I encountered that.

Comment: I think you will get more luck working from python with Saxon C http://www.saxonica.com/saxon-c/doc/html/index.html