# Evaluate Xquery in pyspark on RDD elements

Tags: python, xml, apache-spark, pyspark

We are trying to read large number of XML's and run Xquery on them in pyspark for example books xml. We are using **spark-xml-utils** library.

- We want to feed the directory containing xmls to pyspark.
- Run Xquery on all of them to get our results.

reference answer: [Calling scala code in pyspark for XSLT transformations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47231357/calling-scala-code-in-pyspark-for-xslt-transformations)

The definition of xquery processor where xquery is the string of xquery:

`proc = sc._jvm.com.elsevier.spark_xml_utils.xquery.XQueryProcessor.getInstance(xquery)`

We are reading the files in a directory using:

`sc.wholeTextFiles("xmls/test_files")`

This gives us an RDD containing all the files as a list of tuples:

[ (Filename1,FileContentAsAString), (Filename2,File2ContentAsAString) ]

The xquery evaluates and gives us results if we run on the string (FileContentAsAString)

```
whole_files = sc.wholeTextFiles("xmls/test_files").collect()
proc.evaluate(whole_files[1][1])
# Prints proper xquery result for that file
```

**Problem:**

If we try to run proc.evaluate() on the RDD using lambda function, it is failing.

```
test_file = sc.wholeTextFiles("xmls/test_files")
test_file.map(lambda x: proc.evaluate(x[1])).collect()

# Should give us a list of xquery results
```

**Error:**

```
PicklingError: Could not serialize object: TypeError: can't pickle _thread.RLock objects
```

These functions work somehow but not the evaluate above:

**Print the content xquery is applied on**

```
test_file.map(lambda x: x[1]).collect()

# Outputs the content. if x[0], gives us the list of filenames
```

**Return the len of characters in the contents**

```
test_file.map(lambda x: len(x[1])).collect()
# Output: [15274, 13689, 13696]
```

**Books example for reference:**

```
books_xquery = """for $x in /bookstore/book
where $x/price>30
return $x/title/data()"""

proc_books = sc._jvm.com.elsevier.spark_xml_utils.xquery.XQueryProcessor.getInstance(books_xquery)

books_xml = sc.wholeTextFiles("xmls/books.xml")
books_xml.map(lambda x: proc_books.evaluate(x[1])).collect()
# Error
# I can share the stacktrace if you guys want
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it is not possible to call a Java/Scala library directly within a map call from Python code. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34412182) gives a good explanation why there is no easy way to do this. In short the reason is that the Py4J gateway (which is necessary to "translate" the Python calls into the JVM world) only lives on the driver node while the map calls that you are trying to execute are running on the executor nodes.

One way around that problem would be to wrap the XQuery function in a Scala UDF (explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33257733)), but it still would be necessary to write a few lines of Scala code.

*EDIT*: If you are able to switch from XQuery to XPath, a probably easier option is to change the (XPath) library. [ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) is an XML libary written in Python and also [XPath](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#elementtree-xpath).

The code

```python
xmls = spark.sparkContext.wholeTextFiles("xmls/test_files")
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
xpathquery = "...your query..."
xmls.flatMap(lambda x: ET.fromstring(x[1]).findall(xpathquery)) \
    .map(lambda x: x.text) \
    .foreach(print)
```

would print all results of running the `xpathquery` against all documents loaded from the directory `xmls/test_files`.

At first a [flatMap](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/api/python/pyspark.html?highlight=flatmap#pyspark.RDD.flatMap) is used as the [findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.findall) call returns a list of all matching [elements](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#element-objects) within each document. By using `flatMap` this list is flattened (the result might contain more than one element per file). In the second `map` call the elements are mapped to their [text](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.text) in order to get a readable output.

Comment: Does it really work with Xquery?
Because for example, the below query fails:

`KeyError: ("for $companyName in  /ReportRatios/CoIDs/CoID where $companyName/@Type='CompanyName' return $companyName/data()", None)
.
.KeyError: '@'`

Comment: You are absolutely right. My answer only works with xpath queries, not with xquery expressions. Sorry. I have added this information in the text, although it probably might not help you. Looking at your xquery expression, maybe you could translate it into xpath (`./CoIDs/CoID[@type='CompanyName']`). There are also xquery libraries available for Python, but I cannot give any recommendation here.